# How to delete DOM nodes based on values of their children using PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to write a PHP script that will delete nodes based on the values of their child nodes.  In other words, I am trying to do the same thing with XML that I would do with a relational database.  In the database, I would delete all rows having, say, a "No" in columns 1 and 3.  In XML, if each of my nodes has three children, I would like to delete all nodes having first and third children with the values "No".

It's easy enough to find the parent nodes with child nodes satisfying the above requirements.  The trick is to then delete the parent nodes (and all their children) without throwing a fatal error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What DOM library are you using? SimpleXML? DOMDocument?

Comment: You can use DOMDocument class to do that.

Comment: When removing all of the nodes in a `DOMNodeList`, the simplest approach is to repeatedly remove the *first* item in the list (`item(0)`) until the list is empty.

Comment: salathe: This would be a good solution if I could construct a DOMNodeList consisting only of those elements marked for deletion.  Do you know how to do that?  At present, I am using a mixed list: some elements marked for deletion others not.  See the above explanation and code segment.  Thanks.

Comment: I assumed you could already do that when you said "It's easy enough to find the parent nodes with child nodes satisfying the above requirements."  

If you cannot, please give examples of your source XML and detail what makes an item ready for deletion. Your code is less than useless currently.

Comment: @Salathe Sorry for the confusion. I meant only that I could "find the parent nodes" to print them out, not to collect them in a DOMNodeList.  I recently posted my own answer to my question and I explain how I altered the question to do it.  I got a DOMNodeList of elements using getElementsByTagName('item') but do not yet know how to do something like: getElementsByTagName('item') where attribute "delete" value is "Y".

Comment: @Salathe I finally was able to collect the nodes I wanted to delete in a DOMNodeList so that I could use your suggestion.  The key was to create an appropriate Xpath query to create the DOMNodeList then to apply your suggestion to delete all the nodes in that list.  Thanks again for your time and attention to this question.

Answer (score 0):

About a week after posting this problem, I worked out a solution and in the process, learned quite a bit about using the XML DOM with PHP.

First, I found that, if all that I am doing with the three children is looking to see if they contain "Y" or "N", they might as well be attributes instead of elements. Doing this  cuts down on the number of child-elements under each of the "item" elements that might better carry "substantive" as opposed to "control" data. It also means my program does not have to "dig down" to look at the child-elements under each "item" element.

Second, I decided to include a fourth attribute, which I called "delete=".  I used this attribute to mark the element for deletion.

Third, I put all of my "item" elements into a NodeList and used an if statement in a foreach() loop to check each opening "item" element tag for an "N" in the first and third attributes.  If so, I set delete="Y".

Fourth, I set up a second loop to delete the elements marked delete="Y".  Believe it or not, this can be tricky, as I quickly found out.

I did not try to set up a NodeList consisting only of elements marked for deletion as I am not sure how to do so.  Instead I used the NodeList from the third step above, which contains all the "item" elements.  I found out quickly NOT to use for() or foreach() loops to perform the actual deletions. Although these two kinds of loops are most commonly used for accessing individual nodes in a NodeList, they cause problems when deleting nodes.  This is because, the length of the NodeList automatically shortens when you remove a node, so, if you remove an element in, say, the 25th position, the element that had been in the 26th position will move into the 25th position, etc.  The counter in a for() or foreach() loop, however, will move inexorably into the 26th position, skipping examination of the moved element.

I got around this difficulty by setting up a while{} loop as in the following PHP program segment, in which $items is the NodeList, and $root is the root element of the XML document:

```
    $i=0;
    while($i<$items->length)
    {
    $y=$items->item($i);

    /*If you delete an element node, you do not increment the index, $i,
    because another element will move into the ith position and 
    you will have skipped that element.*/

    if ($delete=="Y")
$root->removeChild($y);

    //otherwise, you increment $i.
else
$i=$i+1; 
    }
```